# Can't find my app in a dash, something is wrong with .desktop file?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop

I created .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=STS
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/root/springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS
Icon=spring_tool_suite.png
Actions=New;

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Instance
Exec=/root/springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS &
```

I put it to

> /home/max/.local/share/applications

but I can't find it in a dash(Windows key -> "sts" - name of an app). An application is launched fine from terminal using

> sudo /root/springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS

What is the problem?

Comment: Put it in /usr/share/applications

Comment: I'm trying figure this out at work right now, I've noticed that gedit creates backup files ending with ~ at the end, and changes to original files are not applied until you delete those backup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was the path:

> /root/springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS

I moved it to my user folder and it started to work

> /home/max/springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS